# Update hidden DateTime field

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, datetime, razor

I have a DateTime field:

```
public System.DateTime TimeDismissed { get; set; }
```

I am trying to update it in Javascript, but when I update it like this:

```
var pressedDate = new Date();
var pressedDateString = pressedDate.getDate() + "/" + pressedDate.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + pressedDate.getFullYear() + " " + pressedDate.getHours() + ":" + pressedDate.getMinutes() + ":" + pressedDate.getSeconds();

$('#TimeDismissed').val(pressedDateString);
```

I get this error on my form:

```
The field TimeDismissed must be a date.
```

I assume it's because I'm setting it as a string.  I'm not sure how to set the date using Javascript in a way that Razor will pick up and translate to my ViewModel.

In Chrome I can see that `value` is being set as I would expect:

```
value="27/01/2014 18:36:44"
```

Comment: This is an interesting mix of server-side and client-side code.  You'll want to keep the two separate in your debugging in order to see what's going on.  Is the client-side value being updated as you expect?  `$('TimeDismissed')` looks like an incorrect jQuery selector, as it would be looking for an HTML *element* called `TimeDismissed` which isn't a valid HTML element.  Maybe you want to select on its `id` instead?:  `$('#TimeDismissed')`

Comment: Hi @David (upvoted) - My bad, I freetyped it.  Updated my question, it includes the `value` of the field now too.

Comment: Could be a locale/culture issue, e.g. maybe your server side is expecting dates to be formatted as M/D/Y instead of D/M/Y. If that's the case you'll need to either change the default culture somehow, or write a custom binder that parses ISO-compliant dates like `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`.

Comment: @Avish - It doesn't get through to the server.  The default validation  prevents the postback due to the `must be a date` error.